# Draw backs of using findOne and Save with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering what people have consider to best practice when updating a single document with mongoose. When using findOne and doc.save you retain all of the validation that you get with your schema and middleware. To me this seems to be the best option? Are there major drawbacks to this approach vs doing a findOneAndUpdate?

Comment: `findOneAndUpdate` just executes Mongo's `findAndModify` function which is faster than fetching and saving. It is also an atomic operation so parallel requests will not break your data.